# How to convert string including an array into an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, fingerprint

I am working on an assignment of bioinfo.

I have converted from SMILES to the fingerprints(fp) for a group of molecules, and the data frame looks like this:
[image]

**The type of fingerprint is:**
[image]

Then **save the file to CSV file with to_csv**.

Then reading the file with `pd.read_csv`, the fingerprint changes into a string and looks like:[image]

I replace the \n with empty space, [image], but the type is still a string.

I have used various methods:

1. `ast.literal_eval(fp_df['fp'])`, then there is error: `ValueError: malformed node or string:`, from the most upvoted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list)
2. `list(fp_df['fp'])` can't change the type of string
3. `[n.strip() for n in x]` doesn't work:
   [image: List item]

And other methods have also been tried.

May I ask for your help on how to deal with it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I don't quite understand. Let's say you have a string `a = "[0 0 0 1 0]"`, you want to convert it to a list `a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]`, is that right?

Comment: The origin is array [0 0 0 1 0], but with save to_csv, read_csv, the array becames a string with an array'[0 0 0 1 0]', and I want to convert it into array [0 0 0 1 0].

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` doesn't work because it expects the items to be comma-separated. `[n.strip() for n in x]` doesn't work because it iterates over the string character-by-character, so your result will include the `"["` and `"]"` chars and the space chars will be stripped to `""` (empty string) but still added to the result

Comment: @matszwecja: thank you for the reminder. Will pay attention to it next time.

Comment: @Anentropic, I have thought that it just converts the array into a string with an array, but in fact, it converts each element in the array into a string, split with space. Am I right?

Comment: @Annie the problem is you don't have an array to start with, you have a string. So we need to modify the content of the string until it looks like a string we can successfully convert into an array (that contains only what we want it to)

Answer (score 2):

If your value looks like:

```py
"[1 0 0 1 1 0]"
```

Then you can turn it into a list by:

```py
values = value.lstrip("[").rstrip("]").split()
```

But the values will still be numeric strings, so you could cast to `int` by:

```py
values = [int(n) for n in value.lstrip("[").rstrip("]").split()]
```

Comment: Another way of doing the same thing: `values = list(map(int, value[1:-1].split()))`

Comment: @ImranD indeed   maybe the slice `value[1:-1]` is nicer, more concise

Comment: Thank you for your great help! I am thinking whether it is possible to have another way to save the file to avoid the further data process: to save an array as an array in CSV? Because each fp is a vector 2048x1, the conversion takes time.

Comment: @Annie easiest is probably to use JSON, so when writing the value to a column in the csv file you can use `json.dumps(value)` (and `import json` at top of your python script)

Comment: if you do that you can then use `json.loads(value)` when reading the column, instead of needing this strip/split/map

Comment: @ImranD, it is concise. May I ask how these parameters[1:-1] come? It seems [1:-1],[1:-2],[1:-3] all work, [1:0][2:0] etc. don't work. When googling, most of them explain input(), but don't find the explanation for these parameters.

Comment: see https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-list-slice/